# jquery tools validator not clearing errors for inputs set by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I have two types of fields that are validating fine, but the values are set by javascript and the errors for these inputs are not being cleared.  One is the dateinput from jquery tools.  The other is a handwritten one that sets an input based on a radio selection via js.  The forms are on an overlay so this may complicate things a little.

This one should be straight forward.

```
<input class="date" id="startDate" name="meters[0].startDate" required="required"/>
```

The other is an input hidden where I want the message to display

style:

```
        /* workaround for validation message of psuedo hidden input for meter number */
    .noShow {
        height: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
        margin: -20px 0 0 100px;
    }
```

tag:

```
<input class="noShow" data-message="You must select a meter from above search results." id="meterNumber" name="meters[0].number" required="required"/>
```

script for radio button change:

```
$('input[name="selectedMeter"]').change(function() {
     $('#meterNumber').val($('input[name="selectedMeter"]:checked').val());
 });
```

I have tried capturing the change event of the dateinput and triggering various events.  The message will clear if I go to the input and manually do a key input.  I could not simulate this in code, not sure what happens inside the dateinput.

Thanks